# Draw complex network diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I wanna draw a picture in LaTeX like this:
[image: graphic]

But I have no experience how to achieve it.

Comment: Starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: Search for *neural network* here on the site (search box in top right), and you will probably find some examples that get you part of  the way. Then you can ask more specific question about the things you cannot do.

Comment: @Jingwei: Here at TeX.SX we show gratitude towards others by upvoting: to keep the questions, answers, and comments free of "Thanks" content.